# command for checking SMTP log and POP logs for a specific email address

Tags: email, centos, gmail, imap, smtp

My domain was recently hacked and used for spamming and blacklisted by google gmail. I have done the cleanup and updates now requesting a delisting from google.

My system is CentOS, and I know it uses exim mail server. If I need to get the log for a recent transaction to abc@gmail.com where do I look for the SMTP log and POP log? (my email client users IMAP instead of POP).

> For the most recent affected transaction, include your server's SMTP logs for general delivery problems and POP logs for Mail Fetcher problems

Answer (score 0):

Try
    for i in `grep -i "abc@gmail.com" /var/log/maillog | awk '{print $5}'`; do grep -i $i /var/log/maillog; done

Found this in https://serverfault.com/questions/364685/what-command-can-i-use-to-search-sendmail-logs-for-all-message-details-involving#364712